# Is addEventListener a built-in JS function or it's provided by web api?

Tags: javascript, api, web

If JavaScript is considered as single threaded, synchronous programming language, then why we have async functions like addEventListener with JavaScript. Are they really part of JS or provided by WEB APIs?

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score 0):

The MDN Web Docs lists the addEventListener() function unter the EventTarget WebAPI [See Nav bar on the MDN Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPSEJ.png)

So functions like addEventListener are likely provided by WEB APIs. The WebAPIs work basically as their own thread that can process stuff like an event Listener or setTimeout. If you would like to know how the browser works with your code and WebAPIs i can recommend this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

The Video explains, that a called function from your code on runtime gets pushed onto the "stack". The function will be removed from the stack, if the runtime has reached a return statement or the end of the function. When you call a method from a webAPI the call gets pushed to the webAPI, processed and if there is a regular javascript function resulting from that webAPI method, the function gets pushed onto the "callback queue". Functions from the callback queue only pushes a function onto the stack, if there is currently nothing on the stack.